How can I make sure that a String variable is set before the panel switch?
I want to make a quiz game using Java. I used panels to display different "stages" of the quiz (more like different interfaces) and I used cardLayout to navigate through those panels (each panel is in a different file).
I have a panel called SubjectsPanel in which, basically, there are a few buttons with subjects one can choose from. Pressing one of those buttons leads to another panel, ModePanel, in which there are two buttons, a "Practice" button and a "Test" one. Each of those buttons, if pressed, will open their respective panels and the quiz will finally start.
The thing is, I want all the questions and options to be imported from a .txt file. This would work just fine if I use only one .txt, but I've made a .txt for each of the subjects that the player can choose from, and based on which button is pressed in the SubjectsPanel, I want the questions to be imported from its corresponding .txt .
I've tried to compact the code as much as I could, so I've made a version of the quiz that does not really do what it should do (it actually does not work much and it looks quite bad), but that's not the point. It's to see where the problem might be.
So:

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new MainFrame());
    }
}

The MainFrame file:
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

class MainFrame extends JFrame {
    private CardLayout cardLayout;
    private JPanel mainPanel;
    private SharedData sharedData;

    public MainFrame() {
        setTitle("QUIZ");
        setSize(1000, 750); // frame dimension
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        sharedData = new SharedData();

        // CardLayout for switching panels
        cardLayout = new CardLayout();
        mainPanel = new JPanel(cardLayout);

        mainPanel.add(new SubjectsPanel(this, sharedData), "SubjectsPanel");
        mainPanel.add(new ModePanel(this, sharedData), "ModePanel");
        mainPanel.add(new PracticePanel(this, sharedData), "PracticePanel");

        add(mainPanel);
        cardLayout.show(mainPanel, "SubjectsPanel");
    }

    public void switchToPanel(String panelName) {
        cardLayout.show(mainPanel, panelName);
    }

}

I've thought of making a shared class, that every other class can access, which looks like this:
public class SharedData {
    public String subject;

    public String getSubjectChosen() {
        return this.subject;
    }
    
    public void setSubjectChosen(String subject) {
        this.subject = subject;
    }
}  

Then there is SubjectsPanel:
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

class SubjectsPanel extends JPanel {
    JButton b1, b2;

    public SubjectsPanel(MainFrame frame, SharedData sharedData) {

        setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 2));

        JButton b1 = new JButton("Anatomy");
        JButton b2 = new JButton("Cellular Buiology");

        b1.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 40));
        b2.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 40));

        add(b1);
        add(b2);

        b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                sharedData.setSubjectChosen("C:\\Users\\Utilizator\\Documents\\anatomy.txt");
                System.out.println("1st bug print: " + sharedData.getSubjectChosen()); // it displays the file path
                frame.switchToPanel("ModePanel");
            }
        });

        b2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                sharedData.setSubjectChosen("C:\\Users\\Utilizator\\Documents\\biocell.txt");
                frame.switchToPanel("ModePanel");
            }
        });
    }
}

Then there is ModePanel for the two modes, test and practice:
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

class ModePanel extends JPanel {
    public ModePanel(MainFrame frame, SharedData sharedData) {
        setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 2));

        JButton practiceButton = new JButton("Practice");
        JButton testButton = new JButton("Test");

        practiceButton.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 40));
        testButton.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 40));

        add(practiceButton);
        add(testButton);

        practiceButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("2nd bug print: " + sharedData.getSubjectChosen()); // !!!!!it displays the file path 
                frame.switchToPanel("PracticePanel");
            }
        });
    }
}

The PracticePanel (the TestPanel is very similar):
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class PracticePanel extends JPanel {
    JLabel question;
    JCheckBox c[] = new JCheckBox[4];
    JButton b1, b2;
    int q_curent = 0, n = 3;

    QnA q;

    PracticePanel(MainFrame frame, SharedData sharedData) {
        String subjectPath = sharedData.getSubjectChosen(); // should get the chosen subject

        System.out.println(subjectPath); // displays null

        this.q = new QnA(subjectPath); // passing the chosen subject to QnA

        setLayout(new GridLayout(7, 0));

        question = new JLabel();
        question.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 20));
        add(question);

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            c[i] = new JCheckBox();
            add(c[i]);
        }

        b1 = new JButton("Next");
        b2 = new JButton("Previous");

        b1.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 18));
        b2.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 18));

        b2.setEnabled(false);

        add(b1);
        add(b2);
        set();

        // if the "next" button is pressed
        b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                q_curent++;
                b2.setEnabled(true);
                set();
            }
        });

        // if the "previous" button is pressed
        b2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                q_curent--;
                b1.setText("Next");
                b1.setEnabled(true);
                set();

                if (q_curent == 0) {
                    b2.setEnabled(false);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void set() {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            if (q_curent == i) {
                question.setText(q.questions[q_curent]); // questions are displayed
                for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                    c[j].setText(q.options[q_curent][j]); // answer options are displayed
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

And lastly, there is the class for importing the questions with their possible answer options:
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class QnA {
    public String[] questions;
    public String[][] options;

    public QnA(String subject) {
        // importing the questions and their options from the .txt

        try {
            System.out.println(subject); //displays null

            BufferedReader f = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(subject)); //error; the path is null

            int nr_questions = 3;
            questions = new String[nr_questions];
            options = new String[nr_questions][3];

            String linie;
            int i = 0;

            // reading from the file
            while ((linie = f.readLine()) != null) {
                linie = linie.trim();

                if (linie.isEmpty())
                    continue;

                questions[i] = linie;

                for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                    options[i][j] = f.readLine().trim();
                }

                i++;
            }

            // stop reading
            f.close();
        }

        catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("An error occurred: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

The problem is that when it reaches PracticePanel, the sharedData variable is null. I've implemented debug prints and I've kept some (the comments with exclamation marks at the beginning).
It might be something obvious, but I really don't know what I should do. Also, the code may have parts that look weird (for those who are experts) and I might have been smarter about organizing it but I'm still learning.

If you don't get a decent answer soon, consider creating and posting a [mre] program, one that condenses your code and your problem into the smallest program possible, small enough to be allowed to be posted in your question as code-formatted text, one that compiles and runs for us without modification, one that demonstrates your problem for us, and also that has no code that is not essential for the above. Please check out the link which explains what this useful tool is and how it can help both you and us.

Also, if you have any questions about my recommendations above or are having difficulty creating your MRE, which often times is not easy to do, please comment back to us, and we can help you with this. Again, creating a decent MRE often involves quite a bit of work on your part, but it is work that is well worth it as it helps you to better understand and isolate the problem, a process often leads you to identify the problem and find a solution yourself.

Hello lorau, You should show the code where instances sharedData and PracticePanel and how you pass the sharedData to PracticePanel... although it is better, to show all the code involved.

And I don't understand where the problem lies since I've made sure that the same sharedData instance is passed consistently... Precisely how did you "make sure"?

btw your SharedData class violates bean conventions. It should have getters and setters that conform to the instance variable. Why the curiously named subjecttt? If it were subject you should have getSubject and setSubject. For your use case, you should probably make it a singleton too

@g00se - I think the OP didn't realize that you can write this.subject = subject;  (Or if you don't like using this, then subject = s; where s stands for the name you choose for the method parameter.)

@lorau The most likely reason your SharedData instance is null, is that at the point in time when you add the ActionLIstener the SharedData instance is still null. Sorry, that some of the oldies here are so unfriendly to newcomers. I feel that your question is good and relevant.

Thank you for all of your comments! I'll try making an MRE of some sort and show the essential parts of the code. I am just a beginner (this is only my second project) and I am trying to make this quiz game to help me with school tests, so bear with me, please, since I can learn java only in my free time =)

@g00se As I said, I tried to make sure that the sharedData instance is passed by implementing debug prints in each class to see whether the variable is null or not. Also, naming the variable subjecttt was just a personal choice, but I can change it if it's bothersome. @dragoness I think so too, but I can't seem to figure out where this is happening. Thanks again!!

OK. Naming
is not always a trivial matter as it is important to how Java classes behave under reflective and serializing frameworks

I've tried to compact the code as much as I could. If it's still not good, please tell me and I'll try again!
